# Django Validation not working, prevent whitespace only

Tags: django, validation

So I'm creating a blog project using Django. The user has the ability to comment on a blog post, edit and delete etc. I want to provide an error if a user tries to enter an empty comment. If the comment contains just whitespaces, or perhaps they click on the submit button without any comment at all.

In my forms.py I added the clean_body function as per django documentation. They also mention using '{{ form.non_field_errors }}' in my Template which I've included. Does 'forms' need to be replaced with the form name from forms.py?

Now when I load the blog post, the comment field instantly says 'This field is required' and also if I put a comment with whitespaces, the page will refresh and the same 'This field is required' is displayed instead of the unique error message I have added.

Finally to add, I have put 'from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError' in my forms.py file.

**HTML**

```
<div class="card-body">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}

                <h3>Leave a comment:</h3>
                <p>Posting as: {{ user.username }}</p>
                <form id="commentForm" method="post" style="margin-top: 1.3em;">
                    {{ comment_form | crispy }}
                    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button id="submitButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary primary-color btn-lg">Submit</button>
                </form>
                {% else %}
                <h3>Log in or Register to leave a comment.</h3>
                {% endif %}
```

**Forms.py**

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('body',)

    def clean_body(self):
        cleaned_data = super(CommentForm, self).clean()
        body = cleaned_data.get("body")
        if body.isspace():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Your comment was blank, please enter a comment")  # noqa
        return cleaned_data
```

**Views.py**

```
def post_detail(request, slug, *arghs, **kwargs):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1)
    post = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=slug)
    comments = post.comments.all().order_by('created_on')
    comment_count = post.comments.filter(approved=True).count()
    liked = False
    commented = False

    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        liked = True

    comment_form = CommentForm()  # Initialize unbound form first

    if request.method == "POST" and request.user.is_authenticated:
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment_form.instance.email = request.user.email
            comment_form.instance.name = request.user.username
            comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Comment awaiting moderation')  # noqa

    return render(
        request,
        "post_detail.html",
        {
            "post": post,
            "comments": comments,
            "comment_count": comment_count,
            "liked": liked,
            "comment_form": comment_form
        }
    )
```

**Models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Comment {self.body} by {self.name}"
```

Comment: Normally the field will already strip data from the text, hence it will be empty, not spaces.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Right now when I load the blog post, it instantly displays 'This field is required' even though the user hasn't even tried to submit. Is there a way to fix my code so it only displays this message after the submit button has been clicked?

Comment: @Zursen Remove `non_field_errors` in your template